# how to capture the resize event in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The resize event does not seems to get fired in IE8 . It works perfectly in Firefox and chrome .

```
  $(window).resize(function()
  { 
   alert( " resize called " ) ;
  }
```

Am I missing something .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(e){
   // do something
});
```

You are also missing the closing bracket for the resize function;